# How to append a product & category ID to a query string to the end of a URL for all product in woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I currently have a Woocommerce store and an mobile application that pulls products and category from the site.

I am in the process of implementing android app links in the mobile application and in order to link the correct webpage with the product on the app. I would like to add a parameter/query string to the end of all product URLS.

I managed to get this right by adding the post ID (Which is the same as a product ID) at the end of the URL by using.

I did this by using this function in the function.php file

```
<pre>
add_filter( 'post_type_link', 'append_query_string', 10, 2 );
    function append_query_string( $url, $post ) 
       {
           return add_query_arg('wine_id',$post->ID, $url);
       }
</pre>
```

Is there any way to append the category ID at the end of the URL as well?

I searched the web flat and could not find anything.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass an array with query params to append multiple.

```
<pre>
add_filter( 'post_type_link', 'append_query_string', 10, 2 );
    function append_query_string( $url, $post ) 
       {
           return add_query_arg(array('wine_id'=>$post->ID,'category_id'=>$category_id), $url);
       }
</pre>
```

Comment: Still looks like it is only showing the post ID

.../?wine_id=774